# Rails / jQuery sortable => drag Item on top of each other for nesting Model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

Well, I have Notecards listed as a `<div>` (not with `<ul>` and `<li>`) inside a wrapper `<div id="notecards">`. Sorting them works great with jQueryUI sortable().

I would like the notes to be nestable:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :subnotes,      class_name: "Note", foreign_key: "parent_id", dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to  :parent_note,   class_name: "Note", foreign_key: "parent_id"
end
```

But I don't want the sorting to be nestable like it is usually with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags.
I want that you can drag Notecards **onto** each other, and that the one which is doped on top of a note gets submitted via ajax to the server (to update the parent_id) and disappears on the current view.

I tried to use a second list (outside of the `wrapper #notecard`) and connected them with `sortable.({ connectWith: 'bal..' })`
Then on the outside list I could then run the ajax code for sending the new parent to the server, and .remove() the note.

=> But that's not the behavior I want.

So one idea would be that each note has inside its `<div>` it's own list, where a note could be dropped to, but each note then would need it's own jQueryUI.sortable() code to be generated ???? ~> no idea + clue in my mind how to achieve that.

Here is the current state pseudo code (with the wrong behavior / not the drop on note behavior i'm looking for):

HTML:

```
<div id="dropToParent">
</div>

<div id="notecards">
    <div class="note">
        note one
    <div>
    <div class="note">
        note two
    <div>
    <div class="note">
        note three
    <div>
</div>
```

JQuery UI Sortable code (current state NOT THE BEHAVIOR I'M LOOKING FOR)

```
( function($) {    

    // Drop Zone for parent => Not the behavior I'm looking for
    $('#dropToParent').sortable(
        connectWith: '#notecards',
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.item).hide()
            $.ajax( 'sending the new parent id to server' );
            ui.item.remove();
        }
    );


    // #notecards div is sortable
    $('#notecards').sortable({
        connectWith: '#dropToParent'
        update: function() {
            $.ajax( 'sending data to Server to reposition remaining notecards ...' )
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I think the problem is that sortable is actually moving the <div> out of the way, so nesting will be a bit difficult. I think you're better of using some kind of dragging library and collision detection to determine something was dropped onto something...

Comment: I found this btw: http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

Comment: yeah, i found that one too, but that's not the behavior I'm looking for (I dont want to show the nested tree). maybe you are right and I have to look into the dragging library - although I still want my list of notes to be sortable ... ???

Comment: You could create the sort functionality yourself, it's not that hard to do with jQuery dragstart & dragstop.

Comment: it seems that draggable() is designed to work with sortable() https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable I hope can figure that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wohoo, found the solution for that problem. Want to share the insights I got while struggling through that problem.

First, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vs6ho3yq/

1) It is possible to have multiple droppable targets inside a sortable

2) There is a weird behavior when you sort note1 after note2 and you still hold note1. note2 will be displayed on position one, but the droppable target of note2 still is in the middle, where now note1 has been moved
(in the fiddle this weird behavior is corrected with the line described in [3] )

3) To solve the issue, you just need to add `refreshPositions: true,` to the sortable options (!!! **SORTABLE** not droppable) (line 21 in the /JavaScript Part/ fiddle).

If you want to see the weird behavior yourself, just comment line 21 in the /JavaScript Part/ fiddle

Hope this helps anyone in the future.
cheers

Here is the code of the fiddle:

HTML

```
<div id="notecards">
    <div class="note">
        note1
    </div>
    <div class="note">
        note2
    </div>
    <div class="note">
        note3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#notecards {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 60px 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.note {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.note-on-note {
    background-color: red;
}
```

JS

```
(function($) {

    $('.note').droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        over: function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('note-on-note');
        },
        out: function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('note-on-note')
        },
        drop: function() {
            $('.note').each().removeClass('note-on-note');

            // do ajax, eg. move note as subnote
        }
    });

    // #notecards div is sortable
    $('#notecards').sortable({
        revert: 200,
        refreshPositions: true,
        update: function() {
            // do ajax eg. Update posiotions
        }
    });


})(jQuery);
```